# Physically damaged hard disk - trying to mount it

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a physically damaged hard drive (it fell down) which has very creepy noises when attached to a PC.

I am trying to recover some data. My problem is that Ubuntu is not able to mount it. The hard drive is connected through a usb port because it is the internal HDD of a laptop and I connected it to my personal PC.
Here some outputs from some useful commands:

[tail -f /var/log/syslog](https://pastebin.com/SNuRuwA9)

sudo lsblk:

```
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 199,1G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   884M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   103G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0   500G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0 128,2G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

sudo parted -l does not list the hard drive except from sda which is my internal hard drive.

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/pmUCfV1N)

Is there any way to mount it in order to try to recover some data?

Comment: Instead of mounting it, I would do a `fsck` of the file systems first. But apparently you can't even get that far.

Comment: Yes, I used the word "mount"in a wrong way. I meant to obtain the logical address in order to point the HDD

Comment: Ubuntu cannot overcome physical faults on the drive. You seem to be well into the paid, professional recovery zone.

Comment: I thought there would be some ways to obtain a "logical address" from ubuntu so that I can run a recovery software.
By now I cannot run any software since I cannot point the HDD, it is not mapped